# Icacls works from command line, not from batch file

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012, batch-file, icacls

The OS is Windows server 2012.

I am trying to use command `icacls C:\folder\targetfile /grant domain\usergroup:(rx)` to give permissions on certain file.

The command works when executed on command line.

But when I run it from batch file I get the following error:

`domain\usergroup: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.`
I am executing this command as domain admin. Domain admin has full control over target file and folder. Local admin works no better.
I also get same when trying to execute batch from Task Scheduler.

How can I make this work from batch file?

Comment: Windows can't make sense of which domain\usergroup you mean. I understand the privacy concerns, but if you could possibly include the actual names, instead of dummy names, that might help. You know, if we saw spaces, uppercase, well-known SID's, it might give us some clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by pgr pointed me to the right direction: The problem was caused by letter ö in the name of the group.

If I change target group to one that has no nordic letters in its name it works fine.

Though I got the problem solved, it would still be nice to know if there is way to make batch file work with those characters.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment, the command `chcp 1252` before `icacls` solves the problem.

Comment: `chcp 1252` will use code page 1252 and allow you to use the ö.